# test class failed and giving error as REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Category__c, SubCategory__c]

Tags: unit-test

My test class is failing and giving error as

> System.DmlException: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Category__c, SubCategory__c]: [Category__c, SubCategory__c] Class.leadconvert.BulkLeadConvert.handleOpportunityInserts: line 740, column 1 Class.leadconvert.BulkLeadConvert.convertLead: line 104, column 1: [] 
>   Stack Trace: Class.ContractViaOpportunityTrgTest.myUnitTest1: line 193, column 1 "

On opportunity object i have Subcategory and category as required fields.

Below is mt test class code-

```
@isTest
private class ContractViaOpportunityTrgTest{

static testMethod void myUnitTest1()
    {
        Language_Templates__c language = [Select id from Language_Templates__c where Name = 'English' limit 1];
        Regional_Operating_Parameters__c testRegion = new Regional_Operating_Parameters__c(name='test', Region_name__c='testRegion');
        insert testRegion;
        Lead testLead = new Lead();
        testLead.FirstName = 'Test First';
        testLead.LastName = 'Test Last';
        testLead.Company = 'Test Co';
        testLead.language__c = language.id;
        testLead.Regional_Operating_Parameter__c=testRegion.id;
        insert testLead;

        Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(testLead.id);

        LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
        lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
        System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());

        Regional_Operating_Parameters__c RegOpParameter = new Regional_Operating_Parameters__c(Name='United Kingdom',Region_name__c='United Kingdom',Country_Code__c='UK');
        insert RegOpParameter;

        Account accountObj = new Account(Name='TestAccount', Region__c = RegOpParameter.Id);
        insert accountObj;

        Account accountObjTst = new Account(Name='TestAccount');
        insert accountObjTst;        

        System.debug(lcr);

        Opportunity OppObjTst = new Opportunity();
        OppObjTst.Name = 'Test Opportunity1';
        OppObjTst.StageName = 'Prospecting';
        OppObjTst.Probability = 50;     
        OppObjTst.Category__c='Furniture';
        OppObjTst.SubCategory__c='Project';
        OppObjTst.AccountId = accountObjTst.Id;
        OppObjTst.Contract_Term_months__c = 20;
        OppObjTst.CloseDate = System.today()+1;
        OppObjTst.Invoice_Date__c  = System.today();        
        OppObjTst.Contract_Start_Date__c = System.today().addMonths(10);
        OppObjTst.Existing_Contract__c = true;
        OppObjTst.New_Contract__c =false;
        OppObjTst.Forecast_Needed__c = true;

        insert OppObjTst;

        OppObjTst.Contract_Start_Date__c = System.today().addMonths(27);
        update OppObjTst;   
    } 
}
```

Can you please help me how to fix this issue in

> Class.leadconvert.BulkLeadConvert.handleOpportunityInserts: line 740, column 1 Class.leadconvert.BulkLeadConvert.convertLead: line 104, column 1: []

Lead convert class-

```
trigger AutoConvertLead on Lead (after insert) {
    //Declaring variables
    list<Lead> LeadObjList = new list<Lead>(); //List of Leads which will be auto converted.
    // if process = false ; the trigger functionality is not required for the 
    // incoming Leads
    boolean process = false; 

    try{
        for(Lead leadObj : Trigger.new){
        system.debug('OwnerId^^^' + leadObj.OwnerId);
        system.debug('AccOwnerId^^^' + leadObj.OWNER_ID__C);
        system.debug('ContOwnerId^^^' + leadObj.OWNER_ID_TO_CONTACT__C);
        system.debug('OpprtOwnerId^^^' + leadObj.OWNER_ID_TO_OPPORTUNITY__C);

            if(leadObj.Auto_convert__c){
                process = true;
                LeadObjList.add(leadObj);
            }
        }
       Lead_Triggers ClassObj = new Lead_Triggers();  
       ClassObj.LeadConvertMethod(LeadObjList,process); 
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('--Exception--'+e.getMessage());
        Exception__c exp = ExceptionHandler.logException(new Exception__c(Class_Name__c = 'AutoConvertLead', 
                                                                          Method_Name__c = 'Database.LeadConvertResult', 
                                                                          Message__c = e.getMessage())); 
    }
}
```

Getting below error message when converting lead into opportunity.

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post corresponding apex class also?

Comment: @ranirube Post the code of this `leadconvert`

Comment: Basically it is saying you are not populating those fields when u should be

Comment: While converting the `testLead` it should populate the `testLead.Category__c='XYZ';` and `testLead.SubCategory__c='PQR';`

Comment: @RCS- But these two fields are not there in Lead object.

Comment: @ranirube what is this method `handleOpportunityInserts` doing? because insertion is getting failed at 740 line of that method. I think you need to check the opportunity which you're inserting in that method whether has all required parameters filled.

Comment: @Rohit- i think Class.leadconvert.BulkLeadConvert.handleOpportunityInserts is standard class and method. So i am not able to check in that method as i can not find this class in apex class list.

Comment: @ranirube Since you've made mandatory some fields on Opportunity, these fields are not getting filled when you're converting lead into opportunity. I will suggest you to write custom code. I might be wrong, but this what I came to conclusion by trying it in my developer org. Try removing `required` tag from those fields. This will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is one more way to make it working. Go to Customize --> Lead --> Lead Settings. Unchecked the checkbox **Require Validation for Converted Leads**. This will won't run any validations on **Opportunity** and your lead can be converted into opportunity without any errors.

Refer below snapshot:

[image]

Comment: @ranirube It was a learning for me too :)